# How to reload page containing POST data

Tags: php

I've got a section on every page of my site which allows the user to set a reminder. It loads the appropriate form on the page when the `$addtracker` variable is set in the url using:

```
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";?>
<a href="<?php echo $current_url; ?>&addtracker"> Add reminder</a>
```

It works on every page except pages which rely on POST data, such as a search results page. When the link is clicked on these pages, the POST data disappears and so I get 0 results in the search and $_POST data not found errors.

How can I reload the current page with the POST data intact?

Comment: "and I get errors related to that" --- is it not provided deliberately to make answering process more fun?

Comment: If I got your question correct; You must either save the POST data in cookies or SESSION, or load the appropiate form on the page with Ajax so you don't have to refresh the page and lose POST data.

Comment: Ah yes, I should use SESSION, thanks

Answer (score -2):

You should use form with method="GET"

Do not use link , use form with button.